# LaTeX \newcommand for reporting statistics available?

Tags: latex

I am writing a scientific paper with LaTeX. In this paper I report outcomes of several statistical analyses. I am tired of making the reporting including all decimals and formatting consistent across the paper. I want to generate a \newcommand that delivers a more consistent reporting across the paper.

To be more precise let me give you the following example:

In the paper there is the sentence: "X and Y are correlated ($\rho$= .8, $p$= .023)."
I want to create a command that helps me making the reporting of the contents of the brackets more consistent. I imagine something like:

"X and Y are correlated \stats[.8][.023]." That delivers a clean output.

Since I am not too familiar with the \newcommand command, I was wondering whether there exists already a package or solution for this? If not, is there a way I can code this myself?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `\newcommand{\stats}[2]{($\rho= #1$, $p= #2$)}
\stats{.8}{.023}`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own macro like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\stats}[2]{($\rho= #1$, $p= #2$)}

\begin{document}

\stats{.8}{.023}

\end{document}
```